# XAML namespace naming conventions

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, naming-conventions

I have a C# WPF project, namespaced `test`. How should I name sub-namespaces in XAML?

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    xmlns:local.c="clr-namespace:test.Converters"   
    xmlns:local.v="clr-namespace:test.Validators"       
    Title="MainWindow" Height="360" Width="640"> ....
```

Here I have a convention of separating the sub-packages with a period.. Is it okay?

Kind regards,

e.

Comment: Whatever you and your team want. It's just a local alias.

Comment: I am a newcomer to C# , so I ask - what do people usually choose? :-o

Comment: Personally, I don't create hierarchies: you'd have `test`, `Converters` and `Validators` there. But again, there are no conventions other than "whatever works".

Comment: I have Java backgrounds, and in Java the conventions are like DOGMAS... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical WPF application really doesn't have a namespace convention for the XAML, other than the default `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`, the Blend design time namespace and `xmlns:local` which will typically refer to the current namespace.

In the scenario you described above, I've seen/used a few variants, i.e.,

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:test.Converters"   
  xmlns:v="clr-namespace:test.Validators">
```

or

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
  xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:test.Converters"   
  xmlns:val="clr-namespace:test.Validators">
```

In the end, it's really up to whatever you and your team agree upon.

Comment: Thank you for a concise answer :)

Answer (score 10):

A better practice, if possible, would be to separate the C# namespaces that you use from the WPF namespaces. This will also reduce the number of imports that you have. This can be done thanks to the [XmlnsDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) class.

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
  xmlns:test="http://whatever.com/test">
```

In the AssemblyInfo.cs of your libraries, you'll just need to add:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://whatever.com/test", "test")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://whatever.com/test", "test.Converters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://whatever.com/test", "test.Validators")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://whatever.com/test", "test.CustomControls")]
```

Note that this will only work if the classes are in a different assembly to the one you are referencing them from. Within the same assembly, you'll still need to use the C# namespaces.

You can even eliminate the imports altogether by adding your namespaces to the WPF XML namespace:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "test")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "test.Converters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "test.Validators")]
```

That allows people to write:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
  >
  <!-- Note: no namespace prefix needed! -->
  <YourCustomControl />
```

Comment: Thank you, all my classes are in the same assembly