# Problems with adding EnumMatchToBooleanConverter to my xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls

I am trying to follow [this radiobutton tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html)

I created a class called EnumMatchToBooleanConverter and it is in the top level of my wpf project. It says to place the  inside a window.resources like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

I am using it in a usercontrol so I have placed it inside a stackpanel instead:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and it gives me an error:

> EnumMatchToBooleanConverter is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? Am I not allowed to place it inside a stackpanel.resources?

I just tried placing it inside a grid.resources

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

and it says

> The type 'EnumMatchToBooleanConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Well it is in the same namespace as the rest of my project, so I'm unsure why it isn't finding it.

Comment: `Well it is in the same namespace as the rest of my project, so I'm unsure why it isn't finding it`. You need to add an `xmlns` reference to the namespace containing the class, in XAML before you can use that.

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned this. I do have that:  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hw2_tictactoe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
```

for

```
<local:EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
```

All non-built-in classes you reference in XAML must be prefixed by their corresponding xmlns prefix.

Comment: hmm, I added it. The intilisense pops up when I do the colon and shows the EnumMatchToBooleanConverter available. I select it and now the line is: <local:EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" /> but it gives me this error now: The name "EnumMatchToBooleanConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:hw2_ticatactoe".

Comment: You need to rebuild the entire solution. That is a nasty thing in Visual Studio. I suggest you create all these converters in a separate project, so that when your Views don't build for some reason, the converters are still there and VS recognizes them

Answer (score 2):

HighCore's got it right.  Just to add to this namespace discussion, I thought I'd point out another approach that can help make the code more readable or help you diagnose where certain Controls/Value Converters/etc are coming from (i.e., which assembly they are really coming from).  This technique could allow your XAML to appear like Christian has it in his blog (*without* the xmlns prefix):

```
<EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
```

Essentially you perform some some namespace mappings to consolidate namespaces [**like this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682039/718325) (only works if the files are in a different assembly/project).  So in my example above you have mapped one of your namespaces to the default xmlns, so you would not need any prefix in the XAML.

I'm still trying to figure out how far to take this technique and [**Paul Stovell**](http://www.paulstovell.com/xmlnsdefinition) talks about taking it to the extreme, like I've shown above.

Even if you don't end up applying it to that degree, knowing about it might come in handy if you're looking at someone else's Xaml and they have applied a mapping like that.  Knowing that would remind you to lookup the AssemblyInfo.cs file and check for the mapping and possibly help you track down where a Control/Value Converter/etc is actually located.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take this into consideration. This technique could be helpful to cleanup your code base.